# Merge data based on the key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, merge

I have this data:

```json
[
  {
    "key": 111,
    "studentInfo": [
      {
        "details": {
          "calculated_fields": null,
          "status": false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 222,
    "studentInfo": [
      {
        "details": {
          "calculated_fields": null,
          "status": false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "confidential": {
      "data": {
        "access_control": {
          "private_data": null,
          "users": []
        }
      },
      "key": 111
    }
  },
  {
    "confidential": {
      "data": {
        "access_control": {
          "private_data": null,
          "users": []
        }
      },
      "key": 222
    }
  }
]
```

Now I need to merge the data based on the key. For suppose if the objects contain the key"111" all the related info should be displayed as one obj

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "key": 111,
    "studentInfo": [
      {
        "details": {
          "calculated_fields": null,
          "status": false
        }
      }
    ],
    "confidential": {
      "data": {
        "access_control": {
          "private_data": null,
          "users": []
        }
      },
      "key": 111
    }
  },
  {
    "key": 222,
    "studentInfo": [
      {
        "details": {
          "calculated_fields": null,
          "status": false
        }
      }
    ],
    "confidential": {
      "data": {
        "access_control": {
          "private_data": null,
          "users": []
        }
      },
      "key": 222
    }
  }
]
```

**UPDATE:**
Based on Hao Wu answer I get the following output

```
[
  {
    "key": 111,
    "studentInfo": [
      {
        "details": {
          "calculated_fields": null,
          "status": false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "confidential": {
      "data": {
        "access_control": {
          "private_data": null,
          "users": []
        }
      },
      "key": 222
    }
  }
]
```

Entire Code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
var util = require('util');
const path = require("path");
const { ObjectFlags } = require('typescript');
const { join } = require('path');
const { stringify } = require('querystring');
const _ = require('lodash');

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./sample_data.json');
let jsondata = JSON.parse(rawdata);

let stud_records=[];
for (let i = 0; i < jsondata.records.length; i++) {
    let obj = jsondata.records[i];
    let key = obj.id;
    let studentInfo = jsondata.records[i].data;
    let data = {
      studentInfo: [studentInfo],
      key: key
    };
    stud_records.push(data);
  }

  let conf_records=[];
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.values(jsondata.conf_data).length; i++) {
    let obj = Object.values(jsondata.conf_data)[i];
    let key = Object.values(jsondata.conf_data)[i].id;
    let position = i+1;
    let confidential = Object.values(jsondata.conf_data)[i];
    let data = {
      confidential: {
        data:confidential,
        key:key,
        position: position
      },
    };
    conf_records.push(data);
  }

let joined_data= stud_records.concat(conf_records)

const merged = Object.values(joined_data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const key = cur.confidential?.key ?? cur.key;
  if (key)
    acc[key] = { ...acc[key], ...cur };
  return acc;
}, {}));

var log_file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/output.json', {flags : 'w'});
var log_stdout = process.stdout;

console.log = function(d) { //
  log_file.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
  log_stdout.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(merged, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your structure, this code can do the job:

```js
const t = [
  {
    key: 111,
    studentInfo: [
      {
        details: {
          calculated_fields: null,
          status: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    key: 222,
    studentInfo: [
      {
        details: {
          calculated_fields: null,
          status: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    confidential: {
      data: {
        access_control: {
          private_data: null,
          users: [],
        },
      },
      key: 111,
    },
  },
  {
    confidential: {
      data: {
        access_control: {
          private_data: null,
          users: [],
        },
      },
      key: 222,
    },
  },
];

const res = [];

t.reduce((output, currentObj) => {
  currentObj.key
    ? output.push(currentObj)
    : Object.assign(
        output.find((o) => o.key === currentObj.confidential.key),
        currentObj
      );
  return output;
}, res);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Getting error as "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = [
  {
    "key": 111,
    "studentInfo": [
      {
        "details": {
          "calculated_fields": null,
          "status": false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 222,
    "studentInfo": [
      {
        "details": {
          "calculated_fields": null,
          "status": false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "confidential": {
      "data": {
        "access_control": {
          "private_data": null,
          "users": []
        }
      },
      "key": 111
    }
  },
  {
    "confidential": {
      "data": {
        "access_control": {
          "private_data": null,
          "users": []
        }
      },
      "key": 222
    }
  }
];

const merged = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const key = cur.confidential?.key ?? cur.key;
  if (key)
    acc[key] = { ...acc[key], ...cur };
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: This is not working as I get all the studentInfo objects first and then at last adding the confidential and that too last item

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly do you mean, could you elaborate by adding more details/failed cases to your question?

Comment: Updated with output

Comment: with your updated code if(key) I'm not getting any confidential object

Comment: Judging by your updated output, did you maybe run the code before the array is finalized? You must run the function after your array is fully constructed, modifying the original array after the `merged` array is generated will NOT change the output.

Comment: Also make sure your `confidential` objects already have a corresponding `key` specified before the function is run.

Comment: Added my entire code. I'm running this after the aarray is finalized

Answer (score 0):

I could find out the issue and here is the answer

Didn't work:

```
let joined_data= stud_records.concat(conf_records)
```

Worked:

```
let joined_data= [...stud_records,..conf_records]
```